# I am confused about Recursion in power function

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory

Following is the code of getting power (Mathematical).

1. I am confused,it looks like every problem is divided into one Subproblem ,each of size two ,so it is not forming a tree  because , usually for a recursion "tree" you need two recursive calls. With only one recursive call it is something like a simple list. .But it is a recursive function, Factorial and many other recursive functions form trees ,and their recursion look same.

2.If it is forming a tree ,So is it transversing all paths or single path ?

```
     public int GetPower(int k, int n)
     {
     if (n == 0)
     {
      return 1;
     }
     else {
         int t = GetPower(k, n / 2);
          if((n%2)==0)
          {
            return t*t;                
           }
          else{
            return k*t*t;  
           }
         }
     }
```

Kindly help me ,my confusion will need some explanation .

**EDIT**

```
              (2,20)    ->    (2,10)  ->     (2,5)  ->    (2,2)   ->  (2,1)  ->   (2,0)
    1048576 <- 1024     <-     32     <-     2^4*2  <-      2*2   <-    2    <-     1
```

Comment: `Factorial and many other recursive functions form trees` Wrong

Comment: 1. What are you talking about?

Comment: @SLaks So it is not forming a tree?

Comment: I was gonna start writing an answer, but why don't you test it? in paper, start with, I dont know, GetPower(2,4), write it down, 4 ==0 ? then it goes to the else, then t is GetPower(2, 4/2) and so on... do IT, its gonna help you more...

Comment: @SLaks, it's kind of unhelpful to just say "wrong" with no further explanation. But he's right; usually for a recursion "tree" you need two recursive calls. With only one recursive call it is something like a simple list.

Comment: @anakata i'll like if you will share the answer , i have tried it but it is making me confuse

Comment: I can see the recursion tree here. It's a bit hidden because the left and right branch are similar or even equal, so one is derived from the other in place (which is already an optimization). `2^n = 2^(n/2) * 2^(n - n/2)` ...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt where in the code ,it is making a tree and what will be the branches for example GetPower(2,5)

Comment: The tree is not in the code, it's in the way you structure the solution to the problem. If you understand that, you will see that the second if-condition is the one that decides between two equal or two slightly different subtrees, even it doesn't spell this out completely.

Comment: What is a list anyway, but an n-ary tree where n=1?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt  You want say that if(sub tree is equal), t*t otherwise k*t*t, and this if-else actually handles the tree , I cant even see the tree during debugging ,just in the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to compute **GetPower(2,6)** you want the answer for 2^6.Imagine your delight if you are given the answer for 2^3 as 8.Now you will just multiply **2^3 * 2^3** =8*8=64.

This is the logic that is used.

**For odd powers** like:

2^5

We compute the answer of 2^2 and do:

2 * 2^2 * 2^2

Pretty simple trick, but changes the time complexity from **O(N)** to **O(log N)** where **N** is the power.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is creating a hidden tree, which is transversing only one path